mosquitto_pub reset communication because Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unknown CA)
I tried to connect for remote MQTTS server (port 8883), that not mine using mosquitto_pub .
mosquitto_pub  -h example.com -p 8883  -t "TOPIC" -m "message" -u "USER" -P "PASSWORD" --insecure
I see in Wireshark that the client(mosquitto_pub ) reset the communication because Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unknown CA)   
I don't care, I want to connect to that server, and trust it.
I tried to add the CA of server to my trusted .
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:8883 | openssl x509 -outform PEM > server-cert.pem
sudo cp  server-cert.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
sudo update-ca-certificates

But the problem is same.
How can I tell to mosquitto_pub  that I trust and do not check?

Use --tls-use-os-certs if you want mosquitto_pub to trust the OS provided CA certificates. Otherwise just use --cafile server-cert.pem to tell it to use the certificate you downloaded (there is no option to turn this check off, doing so would remove most of the benefits of using TLS).

And it's not about trusting or not trusting the server. It's about verifying that it's actually the server you think it is when you connect to it. Trust the server all you want but if it's a different broker that's captured your traffic and is posing as the broker you think it is, it doesn't matter that you "trusted" the original broker.

@Brits I tried    echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:8883 | openssl x509 -outform PEM > server-cert.pem   and then  mosquitto_pub  -h example.com -p 8883  -t "TOPIC" -m "message" -u "USER" -P "PASSWORD" --cafile server-cert.pem But I saw same error in Wireshark (Unknown CA)

Sorry - you will need the CA certificate that signed the server cert (the issuer in the s_client response). This may be included in the openssl s_client response if the server returns the chanin (but that is optional).

@Brits I don't understand , when I use echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:8883 | openssl x509 -outform PEM > server-cert.pem I got -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ...... -----END CERTIFICATE----- and that file I give to --cafile  that is not good ?

The response from that command string may not contain the full trust chain. It may just contain the server's certificate, not any intermediate certificates or the root ca certificate. To be trusted the full chain is required

It would help if you are able to share the real hostname so we can have a look at what is provided by the broker.

The command chain you have provided will only extract the server cert, and not the chain (if present)
If echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:8883 shows more than 1 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE---- header, then you will need to extract them manually from the output and then put them all into a single file.
The aim is to get the list of certificates where the last one in the list either has the same Subject and Issuer (self signed) or the Issuer is a public CA certificate that is already in the OS trusted store.

Nit: for selfsigned you mean Subject equals Issuer; both Subject and Issuer are 'distinguished name's and each can contain multiple attributes often but not always including CN=CommonName. Yes the good(?) cases are where the chain includes a (selfsigned) root or points to a public root, but it is also possible the chain points to but doesn't include a nonpublic root and then you must get the root from somewhere else, possibly using AuthorityInfoAccess, otherwise by having understanding of PKI.
